# is there a way to update firestore document fields based on a firebase Auth user info?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have successfully added some users' information in firestore documents.
And I have a flutter app where the Client can enter some information after registration, I want to use that information provided to match/link the authenticated user to firestore using a field in the user document, is that possible?

*note: 
 - the data in firestore is created before the user registration. which means the registered user uid is different from the one created in firestore*

I would appreciate help in this regard,  what is the proper code to do so?

I'm pretty new to this.

[user in firestore document id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8huXN.png)

[user uid from firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvBkN.png)

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is.  You can certainly link users to documents. What in particular are you having problem with, in terms of writing the code to do this?  Please edit the question with more specific details.

Comment: my concern is how to do that,  since I'm new,  ive read some docs on the topic,  but i cant seem to make it work.

Comment: You can add any data you want to any document in Firestore. However, if you pre-populate a document *before* a user signs up, how do you tie it to that user? It would be much better to create the data as the user signs up so you could use the standard method of storing the data within a */users* collection with each documentID being the users uid. So, the question is a bit vague and going to be hard to accurately answer.

Comment: ive actually created a /users collection but the document ID's are different fro the uid being generated for the users from auth, how can I link a new user registration information to an already created document?

Answer (score 0):

you can create another collection and store other info with the document with documentId as same as uid.so that you can query the collection with the authenticated user with uid.

Comment: rather than creating a new doc for the user, can I add the information to an existing user doc already created in firestore? even if the user from firebase_auth uid is different form the user doc ID in firestore? @khadga